# Create a function to hide divs

Tags: javascript, html, hide, getelementbyid

I want to display tables when a selection is made in a form and a 'Generate Factsheet' button is clicked. I've got a working code where I individually hide other divs when displaying the one I am interested in. Since I have several options in the form (and hence several corresponding divs in which the respective tables are enclosed), the final code appears bulky. I want to write a function to hide other divs whiles displaying the one I am interested in. This is the code I currently have:

```
    var tableDivs = ['tableOPVDiv','tablePneumoDiv','tableRotaDiv'];
        var selectedVaccine;
        var selectedTableDiv;

    function generateFactsheetFunction(){
        // Selecting the vaccine chosen from the dropdown
        var e = document.getElementById("selectVaccine");
        selectedVaccine = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;

        console.log("selectedVaccine: ", selectedVaccine);


        if (selectedVaccine=="Rotavirus Vaccine"){
            selectedTableDiv='tableRotaDiv';
            console.log("rotavirus selected");
            hideOtherTables();


        } else if (selectedVaccine=="Polio Vaccine"){
            console.log("polio selected");
            selectedTableDiv='tableOPVDiv';
            hideOtherTables();

        } else if (selectedVaccine=="Pneumococcal Vaccine"){
            console.log("pneumo selected");
            selectedTableDiv='tablePneumoDiv';
            hideOtherTables();
        }

    }

function hideOtherTables(){
var testa = tableDivs.indexOf(selectedTableDiv);
console.log("tableDivs[testa]: ", tableDivs[testa]);
console.log("testa: ", testa);
testb = tableDivs[testa];
console.log("testb: ", testb);
document.getElementById(tableDivs[testa]).style.display="block";
/*var newTableDivs=tableDivs.splice(testa);*/
        /*for (y=0;y<newTableDivs.length;y++){
            document.getElementById(newTableDivs[y]).style.display="none";
        }*/
}
```

The uncommented part works fine. In the commented part, I want to say that for all array elements other than `selectedVaccine`, I want the display to be:

```
document.getElementById(tableDivs[testa]).style.display="none";
```

I cannot splice the data because the selections are repititive (the selections are from a form). What is the way to set the visibility of tableDivs associated with other selections to be `none`.

Comment: Can you post html as well for more info?

Comment: print the value of tableDivs[testa] and see. I think it is not able find the element you are trying to search.

Comment: Also, ensure that you haven't misnamed any of the div's names... It could also cause the error. Check `document.getElementById("tableOPVDiv")` and the others

Comment: Why are you using splice?

Comment: @kurious you will get " Cannot read property 'style' of null" error when you try to set the attribute of element which does not exists in DOM. So check whether element is there in DOM before changing its attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why should you change the display property of each and every division seperately? give a common class name to all the divisions and hide them all at once and then display only the required table.

```
$(".yourClass").hide();
document.getElementById(tableDivs[testa]).style.display="block";
```

You will have to use the jQuery Library too.

If you are not familiar with jQuery then use the for loop to hide all the tables first and then display only the required table.

```
for (y=0;y<TableDivs.length;y++){//you need not create newTableDivs
  document.getElementById(TableDivs[y]).style.display="none";
}
document.getElementById(tableDivs[testa]).style.display="block";
```

i.e you just have to interchange the order of execution. ;)

Comment: Thank you, Sandeep. The answer works. And now that I know the answer, the question seems incredibly stupid :-)

Answer (score 0):

Cannot read property 'style' of null this means that **document.getElementById(tableDivs[y])** return null and can not find this element 
try to write

```
document.getElementById("ElementId")
```